# My laptop's battery drains when in hibernate mode. How can I troubleshoot / fix?

Tags: laptop, battery

I've got a Sony Vaio VGN-Z21VN. When I put it into hibernate (**not** sleep) the battery drains - after 24 hours or so the battery is dead.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or fix this?

**UPDATE**: It turns out that the battery drains even when my Sony Vaio Z is switched off (about 10% every 24 hours)

There's a 50 post forum thread on this 'design feature', but no way to fix it:

http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=299109

Comment: Do you know if you can wake the computer by using some wireless bluetooth device (or Wake on LAN)?

Comment: Good point! Didn't think of that. Have just disabled that.

Comment: Is there any way of finding out which other devices might be set up to wake the computer?

Comment: Draining 10% each 24 hours would take 10 days for the battery to drain all the way. So, it drains faster in hibernation?

Comment: Another thing that can use battery power, like WoL, is Intel AMT, if your laptop has Intel vPro enterprise features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shut down the computer, rather than hibernate it.

If it drains after 24 hours, then the fault is a bad battery.

If it does not drain after 24 hours, then it's not really hibernating. The computer is powering up for some reason.

Comment: It drained, not totally, but it wasn't a bad battery just a known Vaio fault (see Arjan's edit to my original post)

Comment: FWIW, it's not just a Vaio fault.  Every laptop I've owned since 2000 has done this.  Remove the battery and it drains 1% per week instead of 3-10% per day.

Answer (score 4):

The command [`powercfg`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(WS.10).aspx) `-energy` will give a report on power settings and usage. It should show any issues. Take a look at that, looking for the warning messages.

EDIT: The `-energy` option [only applies to Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/pnppwr/powermgmt/PowerCfg.mspx) I think. I withdraw my answer from your case, but I'll leave it here in case anyone else can use it.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the battery drains even when my Sony Vaio Z is switched off (about 10% every 24 hours)

There's a 50 post forum thread on this 'design feature', but no way to fix it:

> http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=299109

Comment: Welcome at Super User! Please read the FAQ and note this is a not a forum, and hence answers may not be shown in the order they were posted. I've merged your answer into the question; you can delete this very answer. And when you really think you're done, I guess accepting Dan's answer indicates that? (But, see my comment about that 10% -- so *are* you done...?)

Comment: Thanks Arjan. Not sure what to do here - there were two correct answers. First, your point about the wake on lan, and secondly Vaio issue. Happy for you to delete this comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of my old HP laptop, this would happen either hibernating or powered-off.  It turned out to be a known BIOS flaw, and updating the BIOS 90% fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the best batteries, as long as they are inside a laptop they always WILL deplete, although at a much, much slower rate.

Because they never really are in an disconnected circuit, there's always a closed circuit somewhere which allows electricity to flow thus draining the battery. Simple electronics, really.